# How to select specific named columns

Tags: r

I am trying to automate the analysis of some tables of data in R.

I have tables like so:

Theta1 Theta2 Theta3 Theta4 Sigma1 Sigma2 Omega1 Omega2 Omega3 Omega4

However, the number of T's and O's varies depending on the analysis. So I want to make the code so R automatically figures out how many theta's, sigmas and omegas there are and puts them in their own matrix to be analyzed separately. I am thinking some kind of regular expression? but am more familiar with STATA's commands.

I think I am close but here is my code so far:

```
mcmcChain <- as.matrix(MCMC) #switch MCMC object to matrix
mcmcNames <- colnames(mcmcChain) #make vector with column names

mcmcNames
[1] "THETA1"    "THETA2"    "THETA3"    "THETA4"    "THETA5"    "SIGMA.1.1"
[7] "SIGMA.2.1" "SIGMA.2.2" "OMEGA.1.1" "OMEGA.2.1" "OMEGA.2.2" "OMEGA.3.1"
[13] "OMEGA.3.2" "OMEGA.3.3" "OMEGA.4.1" "OMEGA.4.2" "OMEGA.4.3" "OMEGA.4.4"
[19] "OMEGA.5.1" "OMEGA.5.2" "OMEGA.5.3" "OMEGA.5.4" "OMEGA.5.5" "MCMCOBJ"  

nVar <- length(mcmcNames) #number of variables
for (i in 1:nVar) {
  thetaNames <- mcmcNames[i] # !!some way to identify only theta's!!
}
nTheta <- length(thetaNames) #n theta variables
thetaSamp <- NULL
for (j in 1:nTheta) { #cbind all thetas to one column
thetaSamp <- cbind(thetaSamp, 
                mcmcChain[,paste("THETA",j,sep="") ] )
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Why not use `grep` to identify the relevant columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will isolate all the columns with "THETA" in the name and store them in their own matrix called "thetas":

```
thetas <- mcmcChain[, c(grep("THETA", colnames(mcmcChain)))]
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked well: thetaSamp <- mcmcChain[,grep("THETA",colnames(mcmcChain))]

Answer (score 1):

```
thetadata<-data.frame(mcmcChain[,grep("^THETA",colnames(mcmcChain))]
```